# How to get dynamic HTML form fields name and value in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

some times 10 fields and more how to receive with request.POST.get(" ") or any method in django

```
ex spec data
     id name
      1 width
      2 color



{% for spec in spec %}
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>{{spec.name}}</label>
    <input type="text" name="{{spec.id}}" class="form-control">
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you,
try and customize it according to your requirements.

```
keys = request.POST.keys()
for key in keys[1:]:
    request.POST.get(key, None)
```